# Compilation error in SSIS Package when running in SQL Server 2014

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

We recently upgraded from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014. We have one SSIS package which was running successfully in SQL Server 2012 but coming to SQL Server 2014 we are getting the below error:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.2456.0
>   for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
>   Started:  4:38:42 AM  Error: 2015-11-12 04:38:54.08     Code:
>   0x00000005     Source: File to SQL Staging File to SQL Staging
>   Description: Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. Open
>   the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors.   End
>   Error  Error: 2015-11-12 04:38:54.08     Code: 0x00000005     Source:
>   File to SQL Staging File to SQL Staging     Description: CS1705 -
>   Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, uses 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91', d:\MSSQL11
>   (x86)\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll, 0, 0  End
>   Error  Error: 2015-11-12 04:38:54.11     Code: 0x00000005     Source:
>   File to SQL Staging File to SQL Staging     Description: The binary
>   code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the
>   designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds
>   successfully.  End Error  Error: 2015-11-12 04:38:54.88     Code:
>   0x00000004     Source: File to SQL Staging      Description: The
>   binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the
>   designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds
>   successfully.  End Error  Error: 2015-11-12 04:38:54.88     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: File to SQL Staging      Description: There
>   were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:38:42 AM  Finished:
>   4:38:54 AM  Elapsed:  12.422 seconds.  The package execution failed. 
>   The step failed.

Can you please let us know the reason for error.

Comment: i think you need to open the package and refresh the connection

Comment: is it because of any DLL references ??

Comment: maybe can help in this things

Comment: I think the problem is that `The binary code for the script is not found`. To resolve this, `Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully`